# regarding pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

i have a function like this

```
void some_func(some_type *var)
{
    // do something a get a var2 of type some_type*
    var = var2;
}
```

and in main i have

```
some_type *var;
some_func(var);
print_var(var);
```

but i get a segmentation fault when i run the program. debugging shows that `print_var` is the problem, as if `var` has no value. `var2` is initialized using `new some_type`, so i think i don't need to do this for `var`.

but when i do `var = new some_type` in main, and i manually clone (copy each data of `var2` to `var`) in `some_func`, i don't get the error.

where is my problem? i am not really used to pointer and memory allocation things, but i think both ways should work. am i wrong?

maybe the main question is when i allocate a pointer using `new` in a function, and then hold its address in an argument of pointer, does the memory get deallocated when the function finishes?

Comment: It would be better if you post the whole code.

Comment: it would take me a lot. my code works now, but as i said, not the way i wrote in the question. maybe the main question is when i allocate a pointer using `new` in a function, and then hold its address in an argument of pointer, does the memory get deallocated when the function finishes?

Comment: The answer by @edwinc is right. `some_type * var` says `var` is a pointer to a `some_type`, and it is supplied by the caller. When you say `var = ...` in your function, you're just changing the local copy of `var`, causing it to forget what the caller had set it pointing to, if anything. What `&` does is make sure that `var` really is the caller's actual variable, not a local copy, so when you assign to `var`, you're assigning to the caller's variable.

Comment: Where did the code break when you ran it in gdb?

Comment: @UchiaItachi The problem is obvious from what was posted.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your definition to:

```
    void some_func(some_type*& var)
    {
        // var will also be changed on the caller side
        var = var2; 
    }
```

Notice that it passes a reference to a pointer so the value of the pointer can be updated by the callee.

Answer (score 1):

Your `someType *var` in `main()` is local to main and the `*var` in the function is local to that function.

So, the `var` in function is pointing to `var2` but not the one which is present in main.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `var` by value. This means that a copy of `var` is made on the stack, separate from the `var` in main. This copy is then initialized with `var2`. But, when `some_func` exits, the stack is popped, and the copy is lost. The `var` declared in main is unchanged.

To fix this, one possible way would be for `some_func` to return a pointer value, which you can then assign to `var`.

Alternately, change your declaration of `some_func` to

`void some_func(some_type *& var)`

This passes `var` by reference, meaning that, for all you are concerned, the `var` in `some_func` is the same as the `var` in `main`.